# Fail to concat a few substring parts using regex

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this string:

```
<IMG SRC="https://ad.net/ddm/trackimp/N347.15BE.COM/B24.28;dc_trk_aid=48;dc_trk_cid=141;ord=%%TS%%;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;ltd=?" BORDER="0" HEIGHT="1" WIDTH="1" ALT="Advertisement">
```

which I want to turn into this string:

```
https://ad.net/ddm/trackimp/N347.15BE.COM/B24.28;dc_trk_aid=48;dc_trk_cid=141;ord=[ts];dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;ltd=?"
```

I have tried this formula, but it doesn't work as I expect:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(K36,"(.+)(http.*?_ord=)(.+)(;ltd=?)(.+)", "$2[ts]$4")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first bit, try:

`=regexreplace(K36,"<IMG SRC=""(.*)\ BORDER=.*","$1")`

For the `%%TS%%` try:

`=regexreplace(regexreplace(K36,"<IMG SRC=""(.*)\ BORDER=.*","$1"),"(\%\%)(.*)(\%\%)","[$2]")`

Not sure if `[TS]` is OK or if you want `[ts]`? You could wrap `lower()` round everything?

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification with Aresvik's answer. You could get the `[ts]` by using `lower` as Aresvik mentioned. But if you want the other parts as is (not lowered), then combine it with `regexextract` and `lower` the result to replace the string between the pair of `%%`.

This replaces `[$2]` with `"["&lower(regexextract(K36,"\%\%(.*)\%\%"))&"]"`

#### Modified Formula:

`=regexreplace(regexreplace(K36,"<IMG SRC=""(.*)\ BORDER=.*","$1"),"(\%\%)(.*)(\%\%)","["&lower(regexextract(K36,"\%\%(.*)\%\%"))&"]")`

[image: outupt]

If you want the `"` removed at the end, use this formula instead

`=regexreplace(regexreplace(A1,"<IMG SRC=""(.*)"" BORDER=.*","$1"),"(\%\%)(.*)(\%\%)","["&lower(regexextract(A1,"\%\%(.*)\%\%"))&"]")`

[image: output2]